# Saving coordinates of 2 mouse clicks and the drawing line between them c++

Tags: c++, windows

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{        HDC hdc;
        int count=1; int xs,ys,xe,ye;
    switch (message)                 
    {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN
        hdc=GetDC(hwnd);
             if(count%2!=1){
             xs=GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
             ys=GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);}  
             else{
             xe=GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
             ye=GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
             drawline(hdc,xs,ys,xe,ye);
             }
          ReleaseDC(hwnd,hdc);
          count++;
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       
            break;
        default:                      
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

I've tried , but there's something wrong with this code.

Comment: When you press your mouse first time then (count%2) = 1. So you have to change you if-condition to if(count%2==1). I hope it works. Regards.

Comment: thany u smith , but it deosn't draw anything also !

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if(count%2 == 1)
```

insted of

```
if(count%2 != 1)
```

Might work then.